# How to set coder for Google Dataflow Pipeline in Python?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

I am creating a custom Dataflow job in Python to ingest data from PubSub to BigQuery. Table has many nested fields.

Where Can I set Coder in this pipeline?

```
avail_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(bg_out_schema)
coder = TableRowJsonCoder(table_schema=avail_schema)

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    # Read the text from PubSub messages.
    lines = (p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription="projects/project_name/subscriptions/subscription_name")
              | 'Map' >> beam.Map(coder))
    # transformed = lines| 'Parse JSON to Dict' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
    transformed | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery("Project:DataSet.Table", schema=avail_schema, write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)


Error: Map can be used only with callable objects. Received TableRowJsonCoder instead.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code above, the coder is applied to the message read from the PubSub which is text.

WriteToBigQuery works with both, dictionary and TableRow. json.load emits dict so you can simply use the output from it to write to BigQuery without apply any coder. Note, the field in dictionary has to match Table Schema.

To avoid coder issue I would suggest using following code.

```
avail_schema = parse_table_schema_from_json(bg_out_schema)

with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
    # Read the text from PubSub messages.
    lines = (p | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription="projects/project_name/subscriptions/subscription_name"))
    transformed = lines| 'Parse JSON to Dict' >> beam.Map(json.loads)
    transformed | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery("Project:DataSet.Table", schema=avail_schema, write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
```

Comment: It works for simple JSON, but not nested. Table has RECORD type fields with nested data. That's where it's failing.

Comment: I would suggest trying parsing the nested json separately to debug the issue. As I suspect the json syntax and library might not be correct.

Comment: I was trying to insert null to 'REPEATED' columns. Changing input from nulll to [] fixed the issue.